# BeautifulSoup "Table soup" won't give me all tables

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape player data from table that have been put inside comments.  I used find_all, but it's only returning one table.

Here's the link: https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ANA/ANA201806180.shtml

Here's my code.  Any idea why it's only returning one player data table and not all?  Also I have the page saved locally.

```
# import libraries and files
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

# Get Page
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("D:/My Web Sites/baseball 2/www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ANA/ANA201806180.html"), "html.parser")

# use table text find comment text
table_text = soup.find(text=re.compile('table class="sortable stats_table"')) 

# use bs4 to parse the text
table_soup = BeautifulSoup(table_text, 'lxml')

# Player Data from Tables
player_data = table_soup.find_all('tr')

print player_data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting all the tabular contents from that site because they all lie within `comment`. The process to get them is slightly different from the usual ones.

Check out [this link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#comments-and-other-special-strings) for further details.

Give it a shot to get all the tabular data from that site:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

res = requests.get("https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ANA/ANA201806180.shtml",headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
for comment in soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment)):
    data = BeautifulSoup(comment,"lxml")
    for items in data.select("table tr"):
        tds = [' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in items.select("th,td")]
        print(tds)
```

Comment: That's awesome, thank you.  I'm getting the text here, but is there any way to get the tags?  In the comment code, the tags seem like they can go into a csv and be delimited by commas.  That will give me a visual of what each number means.  For some reason, in the text, the tags for the stat are showing as U

Comment: ~u'Ian Kinsler 2B', u'5', u'0', u'2', u'0', u'0', u'1', u'5', u'.224', u'.287', u'.397', u'.684', u'32', u'20', u'-0.015', u'0.98', u'0.071', u'-0.086', u'-0.1', u'1', u'2', u'2B'~

Comment: If it solves the problem, care to tick the grayed out checkmark next to my answer to accept it as a solution @user1825695. Thanks.